# How can I format the header without italics in reports without using fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, report

I am writing a report. I set `\pagestyle{headings}` which looks well, but formats the chapter in italics instead of normalfont. How can I change this to normalfont or boldfont, without using `fancyhdr`?

---

Here is an example how it looks:

*KAPITEL 5. INSTALLATION UND BENUTZUNG*                             26

And here is an example how it should look:

**KAPITEL 5.** INSTALLATION UND BENUTZUNG                             26

Comment: Why is fancyhdr to be avoided?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Comment: @egreg Minimalism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the internal heading definition.
Do you use the option twoside? Please provide a minimal example.

The solution for onside:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{\bfseries{\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\chapter{Installation und Benutzung}
\clearpage
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

You are writing in German. You should use a KOMA class like scrreprt. Why don't you use a package like `scrpage2` or `fancyhdr`

Comment: Do I edit this in report.cls/sty directly?

Comment: You can copy the code into your header

Comment: koma destroys the pre-existing layout somehow and I do not like its look. Additionally, I want the changes to be portable to other documents easily, that do not use koma.

Comment: @Marco: you forgot the modification to the font in your edited example? Also, `\pagestyle{headings}` should go after the modificatition of `\ps@headings`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

This is the definition of `\chaptermark` in `report.cls` for the `headings` page style (one sided):

```
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
    \fi
    #1}}}
```

Your needs seem to be twofold: "KAPITEL 1." bold and the chapter title medium face. There's also the definition of `\@oddhead` to keep in mind:

```
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
```

We have to change the way both commands act:

```
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
    {\bfseries\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter.} \ %
    \fi
    #1}}{}}
\def\@oddhead{\rightmark\hfil\thepage}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           {\bfseries\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
           {{\bfseries\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\makeatother
```

A similar adjustment should be done also to the definition of `thebibliography` and `theindex` (if you use them).

Comment: When I reread the question and noticed that only `\chaptername and `\thechapter` were to be boldfaced, I was going to edit my answer just to give this solution.

Comment: @Gonzalo: it seems that this doesn't bother the OP.